# Will building up running reduce knee pain

Tags: running, injury-prevention, knee-pain

I've been working on strength/cardio for 4 months now and I'm getting pretty fit.
Due to a bad hand injury I was avoiding running and instead used the stationary bike and eliptical for cardio.  The injury is now passing so I gave running ago.

My first run on Friday I did 5km in 39 minutes, then Sunday I did 5km in 32 mins - after both runs my knees hurt (in fairly specific places).  Today (thursday) I ran 1.6km in 9 minutes and my right knee started to hurt again.

Its not a severe pain and does pass when resting - my question is: has this happened because I've done too much too soon and if so would resting till 'better' then slowly increasing time/distance prevent it happening?

Comment: Where exactly does the pain reside?  Is it a dull pain, a sharp pain? Have you run before or is this the first time you have ever run?  You do want to build up slowly, but running 3 miles two times in 3 days should not be too much, especially if you have run in the past.

Comment: I've not run really for at least 10 years and then only really when playing rugby.  On both legs its the same place, so left leg just to right of knee cap.  Its sharp when its there but I cant cause it through poking when rested.  Also I'm 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a similar answer, check this [running knee pain](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/how-to-avoid-damaging-my-knee-when-training-for-and-running-a-marathon/1867#1867) thread.

Knee pain does not just go away as it is caused by weakness.  As a result, you need to strengthen the affected area.

4 reasons that usually cause knee pain while running
1)  Weak Hips
2)  Weak Thighs (Quads)
3)  Tight Hamstrings
4)  Tight IT Band

This link shows a routine to address the 4 areas above and [Reduce Knee Pain from Running](http://christopherickes.com/running-blog/why-do-my-knees-hurt-from-running/).

Comment: How about unsuitable running technique? Heel-striking kills my left knee, while running on the forefoot works wonderfully.

Comment: Heel strike does hurt shins & knees.  But heel strike can be fixed by stretching hamstrings, stretching hips and strengthening hips.  Heel strike is usually the result of poor rear hip extension.  The above should help remedy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ChristopherIckes' answer.

I would add that I think you're running too far too soon. I would do a beginner's running program for 4 months to get to running 5km safely.

I would also advise seeing a physio. Your symptoms sound like a knee cap tracking problem which is often caused by weak muscles which a physio can help you with.