# What can I do to rehabilitate my knee pain from running?

Tags: running, knees, knee-pain

I have been running a lot for 2 months, about 42 mins per session, 5 days per week. Recently, I have been feeling pain in my left knee sometimes. I probably should stop running now.

Any advices about how to rehab/recover my knee?

Comment: You may want to start by taking a look at these answers about [preventing joint pain/damage when running](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-run-without-damaging-your-feet-knees-or-hips). As for rehab, you'll need to give more information.

Comment: Where on the knee is the pain? Does it hurt only while moving the knee? Does it hurt when you're not running? Does it hurt walking up/down stairs?

Comment: Squats, squats, and more squats. By an large the best exercise I know of (when using proper form) to rehab/recover the knee(s).

Comment: What is your running technique? Are you landing on the mid/forefoot or are you heelstriking?

Comment: Couple questions - What was your running history before two months ago, and what type of shoes do you wear? Are your shoes solely for running, or do you wear them for other things as well? It may be as simple as the shoes need to be replaced.

Comment: @JohnP All good before. Wear running shoes

Comment: FYI, I visited a doctor, also took MRI, result is OK. After resting for about 3 months. Knee feels all right now. Could because of lack of resting on knee, ran too frequently.

Comment: @gilzero - Actually, if you kept running on the same shoes, it may just be that the cushioning was wearing out and you needed new shoes. I get about 250-350 miles out of a pair of minimalist shoes.

Answer (score 1):

You should start swimming.  I had runners knee for a while and my doctor recommended I swim because there is no impact.